# Change boost.build jamfile for C++11 support?

Tags: c++11, bjam, boost-build

I have been using boost.build or b2 for building a project. I am trying to add C++11 contructs like `auto` and `begin` but the standard invokation `b2 release` in the directory with the Jamfile does not recognize these.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Added the following in Jamroot

```
 <toolset>gcc:<cxxflags>-std=gnu++0x
 <toolset>clang:<cxxflags>-std=c++11
```

Seems to be working

Answer (score 8):

You need to tell the compiler to enable c++11 support

For example, for gcc you can use

```
b2 toolset=gcc cxxflags="-std=c++11"
```

(or the same command with `bjam` instead of `b2`; they are identical these days with the `bjam` kept for backwards-compatibility.)

Comment: I was wondering how to change the Jamroot or site config / user config for this

Comment: using gcc : c++11 : "g++" : <cxxflags>-std=c++11 ;

Comment: Why would I call`bjam` rather than `b2`? Or rather, what's the significance of doing that?

Comment: @einpoklum for any recent releases of boost they are identical. A duplicate executable named `bjam` is included for backward compatibility